# SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn cannot connect using the Listener IP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, high-availability

I have setup a Windows network in an Amazon in a VPC. I have setup two SQL servers and configured Always On. Everything works OK, except that I cannot connect to the SQL Server using the AAG Listener IP from any other computer in the network except from the Primary Node.

I also cannot ping the Listener IP or the Cluster IP.

For the servers the IPS are specified on the NIC.

```
DC: 10.0.0.100
SQL1: 10.0.0.90
SQL2: 10.0.0.92
Cluster: 10.0.0.80
AAG ListenerL: 10.0.0.82
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I got a response from Amazon

"Cluster IPs aren't supported in VPC at this time."

Comment: Have to admit not sure I am confident enough to put a cluster or an Always On Group in a cloud scenario, only just confident enough to put simple standalone, small instance on the cloud.